# sharing AWS Access with juju tool

Tags: juju

I am trying to work with Kubernetes on ubuntu. Ubuntu strongly recommends 
to use juju tool, which needs AWS admin access keys. Is it safe to share?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe that it's safe to share your credentials with Juju. If you're running Juju locally, then you are granting it similar access than you might be grant `s3cmd`.

To protect your account, you should create [an IAM user that has restricted access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html). This is standard practice and is appropriate for every automation tool.

Juju needs to be able to manage virtual machines, networks and storage. It doesn't need access to every AWS service.

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for the reply, i have done the same but juju is throwing error that aws access doesn't have permissions, even the documentation prefers to use complete permissions                 https://jaas.ai/docs/aws-cloud

Comment: Administrator level access is simplest; but it's not required. I've filed a bug to improve the wording here. https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1839737